# How does jQuery implement hide() and show()

Tags: jquery, css

Do they set `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`?

I'm pretty sure `display: none` takes the element out of the normal flow, whilst `visibility: hidden` just hides the element but still has a reserved space for it.

Should I just go download the unpacked version and study it or does someone have a quick answer?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It uses `display`.

Edit: And from John Sheehan's comment on this answer, which I agree with:

> You should go view the unpacked source anyway just to familiarize yourself with it

Edit 2: Comments have mentioned using Firebug to discover what is happening. Indeed, I actually went to the jQuery docs and used the Safari Web Inspector to see what happened on the `hide()` demo to be sure of my answer.

Comment: This is correct. You should go view the unpacked source anyway just to familiarize yourself with it

Comment: Also, using FireBug with FireFox and observing the changes in real-time on elements as you use jQuery is helpful (at least I've found it to be so)

Comment: Voting up - I always develop with the unpacked code in case (well, actually WHEN) I need to debug.  I'll ship with the packed code.

Comment: Thank you, I have never looked at the unpacked version. Though I might soon. I did use Firebug to view the updated DOM an you are indeed correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's also worth noting that Jquery remembers what was there before in a cache. So a `display: flex;` will become `display: none;` and back to `display: flex;`. However, if it was hidden to start with, Jquery won't know what to set it back to and will use `block`. Sadly there's no way to give Jquery a hint, either in HTML, CSS or Javascript to make it do the right thing :-(

Answer (score 2):

It uses display, and for this type of thing you can use Firebug to actually examine what happens to the DOM.