# Hidden div issue

Tags: jquery

I have a div which I intend to hide like this:

```
$("#bla").hide();
```

until some jQuery code fills it with data. This seems to break the 'filling code'. Hiding should still allow the 'filling code' to access the HTML or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a demo? What dou you mean with breaking "the filling code"

Comment: It depends what you are filling. If it is basic HTML, it should work, but if it is plugin content using `<object>` it might be that the object content is not loaded while hidden. Until you share more code, it is difficult to say exactly what's wrong.

Comment: can you share html code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Hiding a div still allows 'filling code' in it.

From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value.

What you're doing is basically just telling the web-page not to display your element. It is still a part of the DOM. You can access its html and such. You can use `.show` to show it later

For example:

```
var elem = $("#bla");
elem.hide();//hides the element
elem.text("Hello World");//sets its inner text to "Hello World"
elem.show(); // "Shows the element again"
```

Here is another interesting question about [how hide/show is implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239207/how-does-jquery-implement-hide-and-show)

Answer (score 2):

`hide` has nothing to do with breaking your fillin code, hide just adds display:none to the element and does not remove it form the DOM..so filling it with other method won't break at all.... however, check for other javascript issues...other issue might break it..

here is the example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ktFxf/1/)

try this

```
$("#bla").hide();
$("#bla").text('asdasdasdsds');
console.log($("#bla").text())
```

check your console..

Comment: May I ask what you did not find satisfactory in my answer that you decided to add an additional one afterwards?

Comment: when i saw your post .. you just had the defination form the docs.. i added examples... just that.. anyways +1 since u added everything now..

Comment: Thanks, I was not trying to be aggressive, I was just wondering if it had a problem in it or if I missed something :)

Comment: :)... i thought you missed examples so i added the fiddle... anyways...no worries there is no problem in your answer at all ,infact your answer is much better than mine now..... haapy coding..:)